# Jquery load page with #something and get related functions executed

Tags: jquery

I have a page where clicking on links some content get loaded using functions and these link have href attribute like this "#section" so on click the href content is added to the address bar in the browser.

I want to do so that when a user type mysite.com/#aaaa the code related to the link #aaa gets executed using jquery is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

To get access to the fragment of the url (ie, the part after the `#`), use this code:

```
// example url: http://www.mysite.com/blog/article#comments
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); // = "comments"
```

You can then use that variable in your logic (which I assume uses `$.load()`) to display the intended content on page load.

Comment: ok but there's a function to execute all event related to one selector?

Comment: for example with mysitye.com/#comment all the function associated to the div #comment get executed

Comment: Do you mean something should happen when the content is loaded? If so that should be done on the callback of the `load()` function. If you could post your code in your question it would make the problem much clearer.

Comment: `window.location.hash` includes the hash symbol.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties

Comment: ok i think i need something like this using trigger method $('#foo').trigger('click'); http://api.jquery.com/trigger/